# Gmail accounts logged in through Outlook

Tags: gmail-api, openid-connect, office365api, outlook-restapi

I managed to log in with my Gmail account in Outlook web mail client without going through the steps in this article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Prepare-your-Gmail-or-G-Suite-account-for-connecting-to-Outlook-and-Office-365-b650957d-4446-425a-ab78-01b89cbead93.
It looks like Outlook has created a new account for me called like outlook_******7620@outlook.com and i don't see any of my information from Gmail.

I needed to test this case because we have an app that integrated with both Gmail and Outlook. We found out that some of our users managed to log in with their Gmail account through the Outlook login, which of course breaks our integration.

My question is: is there a way to get if the account is actually not a Microsoft account in the login process? We are using OpenID Connect for this process.